# SQL SELECT not working within Array MYSQL_ASSOC

Tags: php, sql

I can't seems to find the error in below script. i have been checking for while now. sorry i'm really new to SQL and PHP.

```
    $tCompany_SQLselect = "SELECT ";
    $tCompany_SQLselect .= "ID, preNAME, Name, RegType ";
    $tCompany_SQLselect .= "FROM ";
    $tCompany_SQLselect .= "tCompany ";

    $tCompany_SQLselect_Query = mysql_query($tCompany_SQLselect);

    $index = 1;
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($tCompany_SQLselect_Query, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
        $preNAME = $row['preNAME'];
        $Name = $row['Name'];
        $RegType = $row['RegType'];

        echo $index.".".$preNAME."".$Name."".$RegType" <br />;

        $index++;

    }
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Is the `echo` line an exact copy from your script? It has syntax errors.

Comment: I get blank page, no Data get Selected and present in the browser.

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything. Also `or die(mysql_error())` to `mysql_query()`.

Comment: the extra  brace `}` is okay cause this is in another if statement.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I can always count on you to give that useless recommendation. Error reporting doesn't help with MySQL, and it doesn't help with syntax errors.

Comment: @Barmar Key ripes man, a wee bit harsh.

Comment: No luck with `error_reporting(E_ALL);`, still see blank page

Comment: Here `echo $index . "." . $preNAME . " " . $Name .  " " . $RegType . "<br />";` - this should fix it. You can remove the space in the `" "` if you want.

Comment: Thank you so much @Fred-ii- It was the issue with Echo.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Can you tell me what i did wrong in Echo? I really Appreciate it.

Comment: Was just the way you concatenated the variables. You forgot a few dots. `.$RegType" <br />;` to `. $RegType . "<br />";`

Comment: Yes please delete it. I should be putting an answer to close it since "I" am the one who got it right, and fear being downvoted because of it.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Sure. Delete, and million more thanks for your help.

Comment: You're very much welcome Vilvas, cheers

Comment: I noticed you haven't deleted your question yet. @Vilvas

Comment: @Fred-ii- I try, but it say the question been answered and can't be deleted. :( but i have flagged it

Comment: I can put in an answer then and you can accept it to close it, sounds like a plan? @Vilvas

Comment: It has been done @Vilvas cheers

Comment: @Fred-ii- Cheers :) this php mysql thing is amazing...i can see the power it has...i just don't know why a lot of people say they know it, but when tell them part of the snippet of code they trip LOL

Comment: @Vilvas Indeed it is. Plus, look into using [**`mysqli_` with prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO**](http://php.net/pdo) with [**prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements). That is safer to use, cheers!

Comment: @Fred-ii- I see, Cheers! so far I'm learning this TMIT training course. Hope one day i can be like you :) i have so much ideas/Applications i want to develop.

Comment: @Vilvas You will get better indeed. Practice makes perfect and Stack is a good place to learn from answers given in other questions. All the best!

Comment: @Fred-ii- Thanks bro. you have a social profile i can follow or blog?

Comment: @Vilvas You're welcome. I was going to invite to chat but Stack says you don't have enough rep points. To answer your question, no I don't have a blog, although it wouldn't be a bad idea to start one.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Yeah Reputation is Low :( lol... I have started a Hosting Company, i can give you 6 Month Free Hosting :) just get domain from someone. and is Cloud Base servers. Cheer!

Comment: @Vilvas Thanks for the offer, I appreciate it. Yet, I don't need one, because I have a few dedicated servers I can play with lol

Comment: @Fred-ii- no problem man, anytime... Vilvas is my company name (just google it), let me know if you need anything i can be help.

Comment: @Vilvas I will Google it, cheers!

Comment: @Fred-ii- Since I'm more in design side of programming, We can even team up and work on Codecanyon if you want :)

Comment: @Vilvas We'll talk. I will Google you and contact you. You will know it's me. Now we have to stop chatting, because someone will flag this as being too chatty; which they don't like people doing, only code-related talk. Just so you know, cheers! Bye for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the way you [**concatenated**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php) the variables.

You forgot a dot and a quote. Change `.$RegType" <br />;` to `. $RegType . "<br />";`

```
echo $index . "." . $preNAME . " " . $Name . " " . $RegType  "<br /> ;
                                                            ^  dot  ^ quote
```

Change it to:

```
echo $index . "." . $preNAME . " " . $Name . " " . $RegType . "<br />";
```

You can remove the space in the `" "` if you want.

Answer (score 0):

The `echo` line should be:

```
echo $index.".".$preNAME." ".$Name." ".$RegType." . "<br />";
```

You were missing quotes around `<br />`, and the `.` for concatenation before it.

Comment: I fixed it and still in blank page.

Comment: Check the log file on the server.

Comment: then check the log file on your Mac.

Comment: Here, [`have a read`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25091599/sql-select-not-working-within-array-mysql-assoc#comment39043019_25091599)

Comment: @Barmar i'm really new to PHP and MySQL. Thanks to fred he solved it. But can you also tell me how to check log on Mac or refer me to a link. Thank you

Comment: Sorry, I don't know where the PHP log would be on the Mac. Maybe /var/log/php? Open the Console app and look for it.

Answer (score 0):

first: you can use:

```
$tCompany_SQLselect_Query = mysql_query($tCompany_SQLselect) or die(mysql_error());
```

this will allow you to debug the error.

second: you can use:

```
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($tCompany_SQLselect_Query)
```

to shorten the syntax.